# Opening a new Activity on a onResponse of Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am writing a code in which data from the EditTexts will be stored in a MySQL database hosted by 000Webhost. After storing the data, response will arrive at the client-side, following which a new activity should open. In my program, data is getting stored in the database, however, sometimes the new Activity Opens, sometimes it Doesn't. What might be the problem?

[image]

> RegisterActivity.java

```
package com.example.bloodbank1.Activities;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.bloodbank1.R;
import com.example.bloodbank1.Utils.Endpoints;
import com.example.bloodbank1.Utils.VolleySingleton;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nameEt ,cityEt, bloodGroupet, passwordEt, mobileEt;
    private Button submitButton;
    TextView errorTextView, successTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        nameEt = findViewById(R.id.name);
        cityEt = findViewById(R.id.city);
        bloodGroupet = findViewById(R.id.blood_group);
        passwordEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mobileEt = findViewById(R.id.number);
        submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        errorTextView = findViewById(R.id.errorTextView);
        successTextView = findViewById(R.id.successTextView);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name,city,blood_group,password,mobile;
                name = nameEt.getText().toString();
                city = cityEt.getText().toString();
                blood_group = bloodGroupet.getText().toString();
                password=passwordEt.getText().toString();
                mobile=mobileEt.getText().toString();

                //showMessage(name+"\n"+blood_group+"\n"+password+"\n"+mobile);

                if(isValid(name, city, blood_group, password, mobile))
                {
                    register(name, city, blood_group, password, mobile);
                }


            }
        });

    }

    public  void  register(final String name, final String city, final String blood_group, final String password, final String mobile)
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://busy-programmer-anwesa.000webhostapp.com/register.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if(response.equals("Success"))
                {
                    successTextView.setText("Hurrey!!!");
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //My Problem lies here

                    //startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    RegisterActivity.this.finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Something Went Wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.d("VOLLEY ", Objects.requireNonNull(error.getMessage()));
                errorTextView.setText(error.getMessage());
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name",name);
                params.put("city", city);
                params.put("blood_group", blood_group);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("number", mobile);


                return params;
            }
        };
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    private  boolean isValid(String name, String city, String blood_group, String password, String mobile)
    {

        List<String> valid_blood_groups = new ArrayList<>();
        valid_blood_groups.add("A+");
        valid_blood_groups.add("A-");
        valid_blood_groups.add("B+");
        valid_blood_groups.add("B-");
        valid_blood_groups.add("AB+");
        valid_blood_groups.add("AB-");
        valid_blood_groups.add("O+");
        valid_blood_groups.add("O-");

        if(name.isEmpty())
        {
            showMessage("Name is Empty");
            return  false;
        }
        if(city.isEmpty())
        {
            showMessage("City is Empty");
            return  false;
        }
        else if(!valid_blood_groups.contains((blood_group)))
        {
            showMessage("Blood group invalid chosen from " +valid_blood_groups);
            return  false;
        }
        else if(mobile.length() != 10)
        {
            showMessage("Invalid Mobile Number, Number should be of 10 digits");
            return  false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private  void showMessage(String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

> activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.RegisterActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Your details will be public to the community"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:hint="City"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/blood_group"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:hint="Blood Group"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
            android:text="Become a Donor"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorTextView"
            android:text="Error Message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/successTextView"
            android:text="Success Message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your example. Is your server responding anything back to your client? I see that you are you are also showing toasts both if success or error, are any of these toasts being shown?

Comment: @fernandospr The Error Message gets set to a null value. The Success Message stays as it is.

Comment: Probably it's executing `onErrorResponse` but `error.getMessage()` is null. Are any of the toasts being shown?

Comment: @fernandospr A null message is being shown as a toast message.